# Is there any generic list/table of convex and non-convex functions for references?

Tags: convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am an Electrical Engineering, but I need to do optimization in my research. Often times, when I read papers, the authors say, "...the problem abc is non-convex". Sometimes I understand why is that so, but other times I cannot. I guess that authors make these statements based on the type of problem or its constraints.

Hence, my question is: Is there any generic list of at least basic convex and non-convex functions, like we have differentiation and integration tables?

Comment: There absolutely should be a list like this! I am not aware of a nicely formatted one though. In addition to a list of some basic "building block" functions like $\|\cdot\|$, linear functions, indicator functions, etc., we should make a list of properties which preserve convexity. For instance, positive linear combinations of convex functions are convex; convex functions composed with affine functions remain convex; etc.

Comment: In general the challenge is recognizing when a complicated function is convex.  You need to know theorems about operations that preserve convexity.  This is well covered in chapter 3 of Vandenberghe and Boyd's book Convex Optimization.